# Issues faced while Using Chrome Headless Browser in testing

Tags: google-chrome, automated-tests, google-chrome-headless, katalon-studio

The Chrome Headless browser was unable to identify the element even it is mentioned with an *id* in the test case. While running the same test case in chrome browser, 
 it was working perfectly fine and was failing when I try to run the test case using Chrome Headless Browser. I have set the window size for the chrome headless Browser even the results were same.

> Unable to find the element located by ‘By.xpath: //input[@id =
>   ‘tipo_meta-display_name’]’. Please recheck the objects properties to
>   make sure the desired element is located.

Can anyone help me with the issue

Comment: What did you set the size of the window to? Are you sure the element is in viewport?

Comment: Hi @MateMrše I have used the same window size which i have specifed for normal chrome browser. In normal chrome Browser it was working perfectly fine with that window size but when it comes to Headless Browser it was failing. The window size i have given was 1366,560

Comment: Try with bigger window size and make sure the window is maximized.